# FFMPEG add resize to my comand

Tags: ffmpeg, linux

Hey guys how can I add scale/resize command to mine command, because where ever I place the "scale" command I got error
Here is mine

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mkv -strict -2 -vf "subtitles=subtitle.srt:force_style='FontName=ubuntu,fontsize=30'" -qscale:v 3 -filter:v scale=720:-1 Movie.avi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mkv -strict -2 -vf "subtitles=subtitle.srt:force_style='FontName=ubuntu,fontsize=30',scale=720:-1" -qscale:v 3  Movie.avi
```

All filters applied to a single input should be presented as a sequence, separated by a comma.

Comment: Thats it tnx again Mulvya